# How to manually inflate standard errors to approximate clustered SEs

Tags: regression, clustering, robust, robust-standard-error

I'm reading a handout on clustering [here](http://econweb.umd.edu/%7Esarzosa/teach/2/Disc2_Cluster_handout.pdf)

[image]

It's not clear to me how to compute $\rho_x$ or $\rho_\epsilon$. What is meant by within-cluster correlation of the regression, or within-cluster error correlation?

By way of example, let's say I have the following robust specification:

```
library(estimatr)
lm_robust(points ~ my_sex + partner_sex,
    cluster = team_id,
    se = "stata",
    data = data)
```

Where I'm clustering at the "team" level and the average team size is 2. In this case, what is  or ?